# if $z=\frac {dt}{dx} $ why $ \frac {dz}{dx}=z^3\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, partial-derivative

while solving a differential equation i encounter this derivative : let  $$z=\frac {dt}{dx} $$ i don't understand how they make that $$ \frac {dz}{dx}=z^3\frac {d^2x}{dt^2}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it looks like you are off by a minus sign.  So it should be:

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = -z^3\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$

Then, it follows naturally from a more algebraic view of differentials.  The standard notation for the second derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$ is $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$.  The problem is that this is not algebraically manipulable.  If you find the second derivative by actually applying the quotient rule to the first derivative of $x$ with respect to $t$, the result winds up being $\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2t}{dt^2}$.

So, if $z$ is $\frac{dt}{dx}$ then what is actually being multiplied (taking into account my suspected negative sign) is:

$$(-1)\left(\frac{dt}{dx}\right)^3\left(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2t}{dt^2}\right) \\
(-1)\frac{dt^3}{dx^3}\left(\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} - \frac{dx}{dt}\frac{d^2t}{dt^2}\right) \\
(-1)\left(\frac{d^2x}{dx^2}\frac{dt}{dx} - \frac{d^2t}{dx^2}\right) \\
\frac{d^2t}{dx^2} - \frac{d^2x}{dx^2}\frac{dt}{dx}
$$
This is the second derivative of $t$ with respect to $x$ (using the algebraically manipulable form of the notation for the second derivative).  Since $z = \frac{t}{x}$ (the first derivative of $t$ with respect to $x$, then $\frac{dz}{dx}$ is the second derivative of $t$ with respect to $x$, which, as we showed, is equal to your formula.

Answer (score 2):

Equivalently we have the expression

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=\frac{1}{z}$$

then take $\frac{d}{dt}$ on both sides and apply chain rule

$$\frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \frac{d}{dt}\frac{1}{z} = \frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\left(\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{z}\right) = \frac{dx}{dt}\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{z^2}\frac{dz}{dx}\right)$$

Putting this together with first equation gives us

$$\frac{dz}{dx} = -z^3\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}$$